# C++: Is there an upper limit for code reordering distance?

Tags: c++, volatile

Consider this code:

```
void f(int volatile *pTarget)
{
    // ... code 1 ...
    *pTarget = ...; // spotlight
    // ... code 2 ...
    // non-trivial infinite loop
    // ... code 3 ...
}
```

As far as I know `volatile` access does not prevent reordering of instructions in any way. But how far can my *spotlight* be postponed? Can it be postponed as late as code 3 thus effectively never happen?

Comment: <strike>Your example code is only showing assignment to the pointer, not the `int` value. Either your example or your code is broken. Fix it.</strike>

Comment: Of course. It was a typo.

Comment: c++11 memory barrier

Comment: 1.) [can not be reordered](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) 2.) Side note: If you are not accessing memory mapped devices or similar then do not use volatile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volatile access can be postponed until it is used, or until compiler can no longer reason about the code, but it must happen at some point. Volatile access can be reordered in regards to other code when compiler can prove 'other code' has no side effects, but can not be reordered in regards to possible-side-effects code, including another volatile access.

Usually compiler can reason about the code as long as execution path stays within the same translation unit.

Comment: "code leaves the visibility scope": Can you elaborate? `pTarget` will go out of scope at the end of the function, but the unnamed volatile itself isn't even in the scope. Or is it according to some rule?

Comment: @Notinlist, I am using a very informal term here. By visibility scope I mean 'compiler can reason about what is happening'. I will rephrase.

Comment: It's hard to accept what you are saying and I'm not doubting it as I don't know, but as far as I know the original intent behind `volatile` was to make memory mapped hardware communication possible. If I were to write a compiler I would make volatile writes to happen as soon as possible, so the attached hardware could react. (As I imagine the reading from a volatile is not that important from this point of view.) I understand that there may be no guarantees on language definition level about it, but in practice do they have any reason to postpone a volatile write at all?

Comment: Sorry for the long essay. Imagine that we only write volatiles (never read them) and the hardware does something for us, like making caffe. And imagine that our software runs as a service and volatile writes never happen, because we don't have reads at all.

Comment: "If the result is not used, volatile access can be optimized away" no, it can not. [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)

Comment: @Notinlist, I see your point, however, this is really all that the standard gives us. For what is worth, if you are doing a hardware, you really need to know your compiler and use compiler-specific instructions to prevent this.

Comment: @knivil, you are right, it can not. I have edit my answer, it was not correct before.

Answer (score 1):

There's no upper limit. You may want `std::atomic`.